# JSF Filter not redirecting After Initial Redirect

Tags: jsf, authentication, redirect, servlet-filters

I am trying to setup a webfilter and need some help. My filter works fine on the initial login but when the session has timed out, and I click on any link, it fires my redirect statement but the webpage in the browser never gets redirected. Can anyone assist with this issue? Much appreciated.

Filter

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package src;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.faces.application.NavigationHandler;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

/**
 *
 * @author Bernard
 */
@WebFilter(filterName = "LoginFilter", urlPatterns = {"/*"})
public class LoginFilter implements Filter {

    //FilterConfig fc;

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        //fc = filterConfig;
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        HttpSession session = req.getSession(true);
        String pageRequested = req.getRequestURL().toString();
        Boolean authenticated = (Boolean) session.getAttribute("authenticated");

        if (authenticated == null) {
            authenticated = false;
        }
        if (!authenticated && !pageRequested.contains("login")) {     
            res.setStatus(301);
            res.sendRedirect(req.getContextPath() + "/login/login.xhtml");                        
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        //fc = null;
    }
}
```

Faces-config.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

<!-- =========== FULL CONFIGURATION FILE ================================== -->

<faces-config version="2.1"
              xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_1.xsd">

    <navigation-rule>
        <from-view-id>/*</from-view-id>

        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>success</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/index.xhtml</to-view-id>
            <redirect/>
        </navigation-case>

        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>failure</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/login/login.xhtml</to-view-id>
            <redirect/>
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>
</faces-config>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>FacesServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>FacesServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>restrict</filter-name>
        <filter-class>src.LoginFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>restrict</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>  
</web-app>
```

Authenticate Bean

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package src;

import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.context.ExternalContext;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

/**
 *
 * @author Bernard
 */
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class Authenticator {

    private String username;
    private String password;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String authenticateUser(ServletRequest request) {
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpSession session = req.getSession(true);
        session.setMaxInactiveInterval(30);
        Boolean authenticated = (Boolean) session.getAttribute("authenticated");

        Database pgDatabase = new Database();
        Admin foundAdmin = null;
        try {
            foundAdmin = (Admin) pgDatabase.findAdminByUsername(username);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Authenticator.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        Admin currentAdmin = new Admin();
        currentAdmin.userName = username;
        currentAdmin.password = this.hashPassword((password));
        if (authenticated != null && authenticated != true) {
            if (foundAdmin != null) {
                if (currentAdmin.equals(foundAdmin)) {
                    authenticated = true;
                    session.setAttribute("authenticated", true);
                    return "success";
                } else {
                    authenticated = false;
                    session.setAttribute("authenticated", false);
                    return "failure";
                }
            } else {
                authenticated = false;
                session.setAttribute("authenticated", false);
                return "failure";
            }
        } else {
            session.setAttribute("authenticated", true);
            authenticated = true;
            return "success";
        }
    }

    public String logOut() {
        FacesContext ctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        ExternalContext extCtx = ctx.getExternalContext();
        Map<String, Object> sessionMap = extCtx.getSessionMap();
        sessionMap.put("authenticated", false);
        return "failure";
    }

    public String hashPassword(String passwordToHash) {
        String hashword = null;
        try {
            MessageDigest md5 = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            md5.update(password.getBytes());
            BigInteger hash = new BigInteger(1, md5.digest());
            hashword = hash.toString(16);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException nsae) {
        }
        return hashword;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get a ViewExpiredException in your log file?

Comment: I'll read it in details in couple of hours if no one answer it

Comment: I also had same problem. Below solution is working properly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your filter looks fine (apart from the very weak `url.contains("login")` test and the in 2 ways incorrect attempt to set the response status to 301 and the a bit poor way of checking a logged-in user).

I think that your concrete problem is caused that you're performing navigaiton by ajax links instead of normal links. You can't send a redirect on an ajax response this way. Neither the JSF ajax engine nor the webbrowser follows 302 redirects on JSF ajax responses. The client ends up with an ajax response which is totally ignored.

Instead, you should be sending a special XML response which instructs the JSF ajax engine to send a redirect. It's exactly that XML response as is been sent when inside the JSF context the [`ExternalContext#redirect()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#redirect%28java.lang.String%29) is been used during an ajax request.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<partial-response>
    <redirect url="/contextpath/login/login.xhtml"></redirect>
</partial-response>
```

Inside the servlet filter, you should thus first check if the request concerns a JSF ajax request and if so, then return the above XML response, otherwise just invoke `HttpServletResponse#sendRedirect()` the usual way. You can do that by checking if the `Faces-Request` request header is present and equals to `partial/ajax`.

```
if ("partial/ajax".equals(request.getHeader("Faces-Request"))) {
    // It's a JSF ajax request.
}
```

So, all with all, your `doFilter()` should look now like this:

```
String loginURL = req.getContextPath() + "/login/login.xhtml";

if (!authenticated && !req.getRequestURI().equals(loginURL)) {
    if ("partial/ajax".equals(request.getHeader("Faces-Request"))) {
        res.setContentType("text/xml");
        res.getWriter()
            .append("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>")
            .printf("<partial-response><redirect url=\"%s\"></redirect></partial-response>", loginURL);
    } else {
        res.sendRedirect(loginURL);
    }
} else {
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

Comment: BallusC, thanks a lot. This seems to be working perfectly.

This is my first attempt at a Java app as well as coding in the whole so I am not too keen on the best practices of doing things. If you can improve my user checking method in anyway I would appreciate. 

Either way I am very grateful for the assistance.

Comment: You're welcome. As to the login checking, just don't store a boolean in the session scope. Store the `User` itself. This way you can access its information such as username, email, roles, etc directly without the need to request it everytime. In the filter, just check if `session.getAttribute("user") != null`.